# Browse and select Excell file and create workbook object from it in java

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi

Hi I want to select one file from my system and create Workbook object. I have written below provide code to do it. As you can see I am writing that file to some temporary location and then creating the Workbook object from that temporary copy. But, **I want to create Workbook object without creating copy of it**.

```
<form action="UploadDownloadFileServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select File to Upload:<input type="file" name="fileName"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

doPost() code snippet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        throw new ServletException("Content type is not multipart/form-data");
    }

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        List<FileItem> fileItemsList = uploader.parseRequest(request);

        FileItem fileItem = fileItemsList.get(0);
        System.out.println("FieldName=" + fileItem.getFieldName());
        System.out.println("FileName=" + fileItem.getName());
        System.out.println("ContentType=" + fileItem.getContentType());
        System.out.println("Size in bytes=" + fileItem.getSize());
        File file = new File(File.separator + fileItem.getName());

        System.out.println("Absolute Path at server=" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        fileItem.write(file);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        Workbook workbook = getWorkbook(inputStream, file.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

listener class

```
@WebListener
public class FileLocationContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
        ServletContext ctx = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
        String relativePath = ctx.getInitParameter("tempfile.dir");
        File file = new File(rootPath + File.separator + relativePath);
        if(!file.exists()) file.mkdirs();
        System.out.println("File Directory created to be used for storing files");
        ctx.setAttribute("FILES_DIR_FILE", file);
        ctx.setAttribute("FILES_DIR", rootPath + File.separator + relativePath);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        //do cleanup if needed
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after little bit research..I am able to achieve my goal ...

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,  IOException {
if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
    throw new ServletException("Content type is not multipart/form-data");
}

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
try {
    List<FileItem> fileItemsList = uploader.parseRequest(request);

    FileItem fileItem = fileItemsList.get(0);
    System.out.println("FieldName=" + fileItem.getFieldName());
    System.out.println("FileName=" + fileItem.getName());
    System.out.println("ContentType=" + fileItem.getContentType());
    System.out.println("Size in bytes=" + fileItem.getSize());
    InputStream inputStream=fileItem.getInputStream();
            Workbook workbook;
            if (fileItem.getName().endsWith("xlsx")) {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            } else if (fileItem.getName().endsWith("xls")) {
                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The specified file is not Excel file");
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for the own effort to find [FileItem.getInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getInputStream--) and that a workbook can be created from an `InputStraem`. Btw.: Have a look at [WorkbookFactory.create](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create(java.io.InputStream)) for a better approach to support both `HSSF` and `XSSF`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,  IOException {
    if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        throw new ServletException("Content type is not multipart/form-data");
    }

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        List<FileItem> fileItemsList = uploader.parseRequest(request);

        FileItem fileItem = fileItemsList.get(0);
        System.out.println("FieldName=" + fileItem.getFieldName());
        System.out.println("FileName=" + fileItem.getName());
        System.out.println("ContentType=" + fileItem.getContentType());
        System.out.println("Size in bytes=" + fileItem.getSize());
        // Changes here
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); // implement your getWorkbook without arguments

        CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("new sheet");

        // Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
        Row row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
        // Create a cell and put a value in it.
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(1);

        // Or do it on one line.
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(1.2);
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(createHelper.createRichTextString("This is a string"));
        row.createCell(3).setCellValue(true);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(File.separator + fileItem.getName());
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        // Changes end here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This was based on an example from [ApachePoi](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateCells) webpage.

Comment: it's creating empty workbook..When trying to read sheets of it. It's throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException .

Comment: I edited the example to include the creation of a new Sheet, Rows and cells. This way the workbook wont be empty